# Boolean index for multidimensional array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, indexing

How do I create a boolean index for multidimensional array? Ive also tried data[labels == 0, :, :]

Data is of shape (6000, 28, 28)

Labels is of shape (6000, 1)

```
new = data[labels == 0]
```

IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 1; dimension is 28 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1

I am able to run the following

```
new= data[np.where(labels == c)]
```

but my returned shape is of (num_matching_criteria, 28)

Comment: flatten your label

Answer (score 0):

Are you using numpy array? It works for me when both data and labels are numpy arrays.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.arange(24).reshape((4,3,2))
>>> a
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 4,  5]],
       [[ 6,  7],
        [ 8,  9],
        [10, 11]],
       [[12, 13],
        [14, 15],
        [16, 17]],
       [[18, 19],
        [20, 21],
        [22, 23]]])
>>> labels = numpy.array([1,0,1, 0])
>>> a[labels > 0]
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 4,  5]],
       [[12, 13],
        [14, 15],
        [16, 17]]])
>>> a[labels == 0]
array([[[ 6,  7],
        [ 8,  9],
        [10, 11]],
       [[18, 19],
        [20, 21],
        [22, 23]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do the following

```
sel = np.array(labels == c)[:,0]
slice = data[sel]
```